# How do I do a power in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How do I do something to the power in Xcode?

Say I want to do 2^3 how would I write it in Xcode style?

And if it's a bit more complex such as (2 to the power of (3*3)) multiplied by 5, who would I write it

Comment: Xcode is not a language. You wouldn't write anything in Xcode style. Objective-C is a superset of C, so you'd write it the same way as in C.

Answer (score 4):

There is no operator to do this in Objective-C.

Standard C Library has an `pow (x, y)` that raises x to the y power.

You can try with:

```
x = (int)pow((double)intx, (double)inty);
```

However if the output of the `pow` function is greater than the maximum value an int can hold, the value of the `int` won't be what you expected.

You can try with:

```
double pow(double, double);
```

and dont forget to include

```
#include <math.h>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have access to all of the standard C math functions.

```
#import <math.h>

double result = pow(2, 3);
```

Your full expression would be:

```
double result = pow(2, 3 * 3) * 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

`^` is the [bitwise XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR) operator both in C (and so in Objective-C as well).
There is no power operator. The standard function `powf()` will do the job, however *(`pow()` if you wanted a double result see at **@rmaddy's** answer):*